# NancyFx how to access to underlying tcp connection

Tags: c#, http, nancy

I'm hacking around NancyFx framework and trying to implement NTLM authentication which is connection-oriented, as stated [here](http://davenport.sourceforge.net/ntlm.html#appendixB):

> NTLM is connection-oriented, rather than request-oriented. So a second request for "/index.html" would not carry any authentication information, and the server would request none. If the server detects that the connection to the client has been dropped, a request for "/index.html" would result in the server reinitiating the NTLM handshake.

This means I need to track is this particular connection already authenticated or not. But for now I cannot see any mechanism how I could access to this information from `NancyModule` instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't - Nancy is hosting agnostic, as well as being able to run without any network at all, so it just isn't possible. It also doesn't sit well with HTTP - although you have keep alive, in general you should probably shouldn't be considering it a persistent connection.

Could you auth the first request then store a cookie so the authentication only happens once per session?

Comment: Actually this is the approach I'm using right now... But I'm not sure what should I choose on server side to keep connection information between requests. Is static dictionary is OK for that? I don't want to use intermediate database backend for that or store temp files somewhere...

Comment: I'm asking, since you're probably more familiar with the `Nancy Way` to do things :)

Comment: I would leave that up to the app developer, similar to the way we do it with forms auth - store a guid in a cookie, if it's not there, or if it's expired, then run the NTLM auth and get the corresponding guid for the user that's authenticated.